# Is it possible to add comparing operation in condition #if in ember JS?

Tags: ember.js

I am newbie in Ember JS. I try to add comparing operation in #if condition, but it doesn't work.
Is it possible to add operation in condition #if in ember JS?

```
     {{#if (slide.type == "image")}}
        <img alt='' src='{{slide.image_url}}'>
     {{else}}
        <video width="100%" height="100%" playsinline=true autoplay=true muted=true loop=true wrap=true>
          <source src={{slide.image_url}}>
        </video>
      {{/if}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use conditionals in the template. However, the syntax you use will not work as Ember defines a restricted and strict syntax for templates for better understanding.

Ember exposes [`helpers`](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/helper-functions/) to perform functions like this in the template. You can create a new helper to check if the two properties are equal like:

```js
// app/helpers/equal.js

import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';

function equal(args) {
  let [prop1, prop2] = args;
  return prop1 === prop2;
}

export default helper(equal);
```

and in your template, you can use the `equal` helper:

```
{{#if (equal slide.type "image")}}
  <img alt='' src='{{slide.image_url}}'>
{{else}}
  <video width="100%" height="100%" playsinline=true autoplay=true muted=true loop=true wrap=true>
    <source src={{slide.image_url}}>
  </video>
{{/if}}
```

or, you can use Ember addons like [`ember-truth-helpers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-truth-helpers) which contains a variety of such conditional helpers, ready to use.

Comment: Additionally equality operators will land soon in Ember itself. They were designed in [RFC 560](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0560-add-equality-operators.md) and accompanied by numeric comparison operators ([RFC 561](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0561-add-numeric-comparison-operators.md)) and logical operators ([RFC 562](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0562-add-logical-operators.md)).

Answer (score 0):

In your HBS file you can simply use following

`{{#if (eq slide.type == "image")}}`

given you use `Ember Truth Helpers`